# Vue v-model in two-way binding components communication

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Following Vue docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html and https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/vue/#forminputbindingsv-model
i tried to implement it in my code:
TinyMCE editor- custom input:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>This will be Editor JS</p>
    <div name="editor">
      <Editor
        :value="modelValue"
         @change="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
        api-key="key"
        :init="{
          plugins: 'lists link image table code help wordcount'
        }"
      />
      <button>show text</button>
      <p>results</p>
      <div v-html="text"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
// FIXME HIDE THE API KEY

import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'
import { defineProps, defineEmits } from 'vue'
defineProps(['modelValue'])
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

and the parent component:

```
  <template>
  <div class="h-sceen flex w-screen flex-col items-center justify-center gap-5">
    <div>hello from test</div>
    <div class="h-[300px] w-[300px]">
      <TinyMCE v-model:text="text" @update:modelValue="handleTextUpdate"></TinyMCE>
      <div
        v-html="text"
        name="result"
        class="flex h-[300px] w-[300px] items-center justify-center border-2 border-black"
      ></div>
      <button @click="console.log(text.value)">See the text</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import TinyMCE from './TinyMCE.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'
const text = ref('')
const handleTextUpdate = (newValue) => {
  text.value = newValue
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

but in the parent component, I still cant access or see the text from child component. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: You need @update:modelValue on editor

Comment: thanks sir for time and answer; but why? in Vue docs they dont use it. I have  @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" in my code? can you provide more details/ code?

Comment: That's because on inputs you listen to vanilla HTML input event, and on a component you listen to whatever events it emits. I'd recommend you to search for v-model inheritance or whatever it's named in docs

Comment: Can't access in which way? console.log(text.value) isn't correct. You don't need to rely on both console or template for debugging. The docs don't mention that Editor has input event, so `@input` is likely wrong, https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/vue/#forminputbindingsv-model . That Editor supports v-model means that these are modelValue prop and update:modelValue event, similarly to your own comp

Comment: thanks sir for your time and answer; so I updated the code- and updated this quetions code, but still doesnt change;

Comment: You do not have to listen to `@update:modelValue` just to update the model in the parent comp. Vue will automatically update the model for you. Also, try this on `@change` or `@keyUp` events in TinyMce `(event, editor) => {$emit("update:modelValue", $event.target.value)}`